# Access: Bind Combobox to recordset but disallow alterations to recordset on change/update

Tags: ms-access, combobox, binding

I'm facing an issue with Access Comboboxes that may be a terrible idea or be an improper use of the tool.

Let's say I have a form that shows metadata of a "Report" (things that are common in the report from day to day like reporter, project, target due date, expected total cost, etc...) with a Continuous subform of line items that are being reported (like cost of labor, materials, overhead expenses, etc)

In the backend I have 2 tables to represent this. The "Metadata" table and the "line items" table. When trying to capture individual items being reported the reporter is free to name the item as they see fit, however, in the system we want to map that reporter item naming to our internal item naming.

In order to do this I have a few helper tables and a mapping table to create this link. An 'Internal Line Item" table, a "DataType" table and a "Line Item Mapper" table.

The structure would look as follows:
- "Line Item" table with ID, Name, Metadata_ID and data (typical excel format)
- "Metadata" table with ID, and metadata common to all reports
- "Internal Line Item" table with ID and Name
- "Line Item Mapper" table with Internal_ID, LineItem_ID and DataType
- "DataType" table with ID and Name

So on to what I am having trouble doing.

I want to display a combo box in the subform for each row and the drop down will have a list of possible internal names that can be selected. I thought that by using an unbound box I could do this, but found that each row would get a copy of the same box (thus changing the selection for all rows at the same time).

I then tried to bind the box to the recordset using the ControlSource, but it changed id numbers when doing so (obviously not ok).

I then thought to tie the box to the Mapping table itself, but don't know how to couple it to the recordset as well...

What I want to do is bind this box to the recordset without allowing it to change any data in the "List Item" table because this box is meant to change the mapping table. I could then use the OnChange event to populate or update the mapping table with the proper data.

Is it possible to create such a binding (where the control is tied to a recordset, allowing me to get the LineItem ID, but not able to change the recordset while still allowing the user to interact with it)? Or is there a better way to approach this issue?

Comment: Comboboxes can certainly be 'unbound' - no ControlSource. Selecting item from list or typing into box should not change the table that RowSource pulls list from. If it does, then the ControlSource is set to wrong field.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! But I think you misunderstand me. I don't want to change the ControlSource even if the Rowsource is changed. I.E. I want to bind the Combobox to the row and select something from the RowSource, but disable any "Auto updates" that Access does and handle the data myself...

Comment: You're right. Don't understand. If combobox is bound to field then selection is passed directly to table record. If combobox is unbound then it won't. So with unbound combobox, use conditional code in some event to determine what to do with selection.

Comment: Correct that is exactly what I need to do. But if I may point you to the section where I  mention that I am using this Unbound Combobox in a Continuous subform, I found out that it copies the box to each row. So I need to Bind the box without allowing it to change any data in the ControlSource....

Comment: Yes, that is drawback of unbound control in Continuous or Datasheet view. All records will display the same info. If you bind it then still use code in some event to decide what to do with the input, perhaps form BeforeUpdate event to 'validate' the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was just doing something foolish with my data model that lead to my troubles.

the full answer may be found here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-msoffice_custom-mso_2013_release/bind-a-control-without-data-alteration-access-2013/51a98460-6e1a-425d-8f7b-eba5f2825ba9?tm=1552503037022&auth=1&page=2

but the short of it is that I was improperly placing all my FK's in a single table trying to make a form of "mapping" table. I have since corrected my structure and have gotten my combobox to work as intended.